# Dropwizard 0.6.2 File Upload

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, dropwizard

i used drop-wizard 0.6.2 framework to develop my rest API .so i have not idea regarding upload the file.the upload file can be done in higher version but i cant upgrade because of lots of modification so any idea of uploading file in drop wizard 0.6.2 ?.

Comment: Perhaps a good time to upgrade to a newest version, it is a 4 years old version

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a client uploading a file to your REST API you can always do the following:

```
@Path("/processFile")
@Consumes("application/octet-stream")
@Produces("application/json")
public String processUploadedFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".data");
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, tempFile);
    // do sth with tempFile
    return "{\"status\": \"ok\"}";
}
```